# auto-adding of 'px' suffix to style values in react.rb

Tags: ruby, inline-styles, react.rb

I've noticed that when I try to set the z-index of a page element using inline style, px gets added to the value automatically but z-index needs a number not a pixel value.

So the web-browser won't accept it as a valid value and so Z-index effectively doesn't work because of it.

I'm doing

```
{
  "z-index" => -1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style attributes should be specified in **camel case**. For css `z-index: -1;` write `{ zIndex: -1 }`.

React.js converts css declarations from camel case to their proper format

React also automatically adds the 'px' suffix to unit-less property values, with some exception as outlined in [these docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/style-props-value-px.html).

Comment: I see, I think it's stupid but I guess if that's the way it has to be then that's the way it has to be.

Comment: The choice was most likely made by the React.js team to play nice with JSON key formatting. React.rb currently has an open issue regarding how to better handle this situation: https://github.com/zetachang/react.rb/issues/108 .